# How to join a lookup table for multple colums of primary table in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, join

I have two tables.  the employee (lookup) table has empl_id and empl_name plus other fields.   The orders (primary) table has order_nbr, cashier_id, cashout_id, and driver_id.    These all include matches to the empl_id in the employee table.

How can I show cashier name, cashout name and driver name in an orders report?

used left join for cashier_id matching empl_id and that works, but i cannot get cashout and driver names to print correctly, always shows the cashier_is's name in all three columns.

```
SELECT
--    "orders_tbl"."cashier_id" AS "cashierID",
--    "orders_tbl"."cashout_id" AS "cashoutID",
--    "orders_tbl"."driver_id" AS "driverID",

    "orders_tbl"."order_number" AS "Order",
    DATE("orders_tbl"."order_entry_date") AS "Date",
    "orders_tbl"."order_entry_time" AS "Time",
 
 
    o.order_number,
    o.cashier_id, e2.empl_name as cashier_name,
    o.cashout_id, e3.empl_name as cashout_name,
    o.driver_id, e4.empl_name as driver_name,


    CASE 
     WHEN  SUBSTR("orders_tbl"."customer_print_name",1,3) = "WEB" THEN "on-line"
     ELSE "employees_tbl"."employeeID"
    END "Cashier",

    CASE
     WHEN SUBSTR("orders_tbl"."customer_print_name",1,3) = "WEB" AND "Orders_tbl"."cashout_id" = 0 THEN "pd online"
     WHEN SUBSTR("orders_tbl"."customer_print_name",1,3) = "WEB" AND "Orders_tbl"."cashout_id" <> 0 THEN "Orders_tbl"."cashier_id" 
     WHEN SUBSTR("orders_tbl"."customer_print_name",1,3) = "WEB" AND "Orders_tbl"."cashier_id" = 0 THEN "employees_tbl"."employeeID" -- should be employee name for cashout for web pay at counter, but comes up 0
     WHEN SUBSTR("orders_tbl"."customer_print_name",1,3) <> "WEB" THEN "employees_tbl"."EmployeeID"
     ELSE  "CASHOUT"
    END "Cashout",
    
--    CASE
--     WHEN "orders_tbl"."driver_id" <> 0 THEN "orders_tbl"."driver_id"
--    END "Driver",

    "orders_tbl"."customer_print_name" AS "Customer",

    CASE "orders_tbl"."order_type"
     WHEN 1 THEN "Take-out"
     WHEN 2 THEN "Dine-in"
     WHEN 3 THEN "Delivery"
     ELSE ""
   END "Type",

    "orders_tbl"."ord_total" AS "Order $",

    CASE "orders_tbl"."discount"
     WHEN 0 then ""
     ELSE "$"||discount
    END "Disc. $"

--    "Order_Items_tbl"."item_qty" AS "Qty",
--    "Order_Items_tbl"."actual_charge" * "Order_Items_tbl"."item_qty" AS "SubTot $",
--    "Order_Items_Tbl"."item_desc" AS "Item"
FROM "orders_tbl"

left join employees_tbl e2
        on o.cashier_id = e2.employee_id
left join employees_tbl e3
        on o.cashout_id = e3.employee_id
left join employees_tbl e4
        on o.driver_id = e4.employee_id

WHERE ("orders_tbl"."record_type" = 1 OR "orders_tbl"."record_type" = 5 OR "orders_tbl"."record_type" = 6) 
    AND "orders_tbl"."voided_order" = 0
    AND date("orders_tbl"."order_date") BETWEEN date('now','-3 days','localtime') AND date('now','localtime')

ORDER BY "orders_tbl"."order_date" DESC
```

Comment: Try putting the JOINS after all the SELECTs and you are missing a "FROM" keyword. As written this SQL is not in the right order and cannot run without errors.

Comment: i made the changes, getting error  no such column: o.order_number  will repost my code above

Comment: you need to change `o.order_number` to `"orders_tbl".order_number` ... and so on wherever `o` is used as an alias (because you aren't actually using that alias).

Comment: @topsail, did so and got further along.   now does not see:  no such column:employees_tbl.employeeID.    i suppose that's from line 8

Comment: yes, all your employees tables are aliased (e2, e3, e4). They are also all left-joined, so no guarantee of matching records. Is one of these employees always present (cashier, or driver, or cashout)?

Comment: cashier always present

Comment: i really di appreciate your help with these nuances.   I just dabble in this stuff self learned.  have a restaurant and want better metrics of the business day to day, month to month etc.

Comment: no problem. If cashier is already present ... `"employees_tbl"."employeeID"` can best be replaced with `e2.employeeID`

Comment: That's what i have.   the above code precisely results in error code: no such column:employees_tbl.employeeID.    i suppose its interpreting e2.employeeID as cashier_name as employees_tbl.employeeID

Comment: its looks like the message is accurate (*no such column employees_tbl.employeeID*) ... I think your employee_tbl actually has a column `employee_id` not `employeeID`

Comment: I think I have it.    instead of referencing cashier_ID as e2 and since there is always a cashier_ID for each record, i reference that directly in the SELECT group and in the JOIN group.  seems to be working verifying now.   thanks for all the help.  I'll post the code once verified.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for support @topsail   Here is my final code.

SELECT
"orders_tbl"."order_number" AS "Order",
--   DATE("orders_tbl"."order_entry_date") AS "Date",

```
case cast (strftime('%w', DATE("orders_tbl"."order_entry_date")) as integer)
 when 0 then 'Sunday'
 when 1 then 'Monday'
 when 2 then 'Tuesday'
 when 3 then 'Wednesday'
 when 4 then 'Thursday'
 when 5 then 'Friday'
 else 'Saturday' 
end as Day,


"orders_tbl"."order_entry_time" AS "Time",

CASE 
 WHEN  SUBSTR("orders_tbl"."customer_print_name",1,3) = "WEB" THEN "ON-LINE"
 ELSE "employees_tbl"."employeeID"
END "Cashier",

CASE
 WHEN SUBSTR("orders_tbl"."customer_print_name",1,3) = "WEB" AND "Orders_tbl"."cashout_id" = 0 THEN "ON-LINE" ELSE e3.employeeID
END "Cashout",

CASE
 WHEN "orders_tbl"."driver_id" <> 0 THEN e4.employeeID
END "Driver",

CASE
 WHEN "orders_tbl"."customer_print_name" = "Walk-In Customer" THEN "walk in" 
 WHEN SUBSTR("orders_tbl"."customer_print_name",1,3) = "[V]" THEN SUBSTR("orders_tbl"."customer_print_name",4)
 WHEN SUBSTR("orders_tbl"."customer_print_name",1,4) = "WEB:" THEN SUBSTR("orders_tbl"."customer_print_name",5)
 ELSE "orders_tbl"."customer_print_name"
END "Customer",

CASE "orders_tbl"."order_type"
 WHEN 1 THEN "take-out"
 WHEN 2 THEN "dine-in"
 WHEN 3 THEN "delivery"
 ELSE ""
```

END "Type",

```
"orders_tbl"."ord_total" AS "Order $",
SUM("orders_tbl"."ord_total") OVER(PARTITION BY "orders_tbl"."order_entry_date") "Daily $",    --USES PARTITION to total daily sales

CASE "orders_tbl"."discount"
 WHEN 0 then null
 ELSE discount
END "Disc. $",

CASE "orders_tbl"."tip_amt"
 WHEN 0 then null
 ELSE tip_amt
END "Tip $",

CASE "orders_tbl"."credit_card_tot"
 WHEN 0 then null
 ELSE "orders_tbl"."credit_card_tot"
END "cc $",

CASE "orders_tbl"."cash_tot"
 WHEN 0 then null
 ELSE "orders_tbl"."cash_tot" - "Orders_tbl"."change_amt"
END "Cash $"
```

--    "Order_Items_tbl"."item_qty" AS "Qty",
--    "Order_Items_tbl"."actual_charge" * "Order_Items_tbl"."item_qty" AS "SubTot $",
--    "Order_Items_Tbl"."item_desc" AS "Item"

FROM orders_tbl

LEFT JOIN "employees_tbl"
ON "Orders_tbl"."cashier_id" = "employees_tbl"."employeeNum"
left join employees_tbl e3
on "orders_tbl".cashout_id = e3.employeeNum
left join employees_tbl e4
on "orders_tbl".driver_id = e4.employeeNum

WHERE ("orders_tbl"."record_type" = 1 OR "orders_tbl"."record_type" = 5 OR "orders_tbl"."record_type" = 6)
AND "orders_tbl"."voided_order" = 0
AND date("orders_tbl"."order_date") BETWEEN date('now','-3 days','localtime') AND date('now','localtime')

ORDER BY "orders_tbl"."order_date" DESC